# MySql number as text division

Tags: mysql

I have numbers stored as varchar in the table (I know it's bad practice but the data comes not from me), and I want to divide them with 25.4, round to integer (so 9,448 should be 10), and store as tinyint(2) unsigned. If the varchar value is 240, after division I get 9 what is incorrect. If I `CAST` 240 to `DECIMAL` (I have to use decimal because sometimes the they are like 240,5) then it gives correct result after division (however I have to `ROUND` it 4x with 3, 2, 1, 0 decimal places), but I can't update the table with this command:

```
UPDATE `table` SET dz = ROUND(ROUND(ROUND(ROUND(CAST(REPLACE(d, ',', '.') AS DECIMAL (6,1))/25.4, 3), 2), 1), 0);
```

because I'm getting the following error message, what drives me crazy:

> Incorrect DECIMAL value: '0' for column '' at row -1

because in the select it works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d, ROUND(ROUND(ROUND(ROUND(CAST(REPLACE(d, ',', '.') AS DECIMAL (6,1))/25.4, 3), 2), 1), 0) AS dz FROM `table`;
```

what is going on here...? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Has to be data .I can (I think) reproduce your error as below (see last insert value)

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (d varchar(10), dz tinyint(2));

insert into t values
('240',null),
('240,5',null),
('9,448',null),
('240 ',null),
('240,',null),
(' ,1',null),
('1,0',null),
('0 ,1',null);
MariaDB [sandbox]> UPDATE t SET dz =
    -> ROUND(
    -> ROUND(
    -> ROUND(
    -> ROUND(
    -> CAST(REPLACE(trim(d), ',', '.') AS DECIMAL (6,1))/25.4
    -> , 3)
    -> , 2)
    -> , 1)
    -> , 0);
ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: '0 .1'
MariaDB [sandbox]>
```

As you say the select has no problem

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select *,
    -> REPLACE(d, ',', '.')
    -> ,CAST(REPLACE(trim(d), ',', '.') AS DECIMAL (6,1))/25.4
    ->  from t;
+-------+------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| d     | dz   | REPLACE(d, ',', '.') | CAST(REPLACE(trim(d), ',', '.') AS DECIMAL (6,1))/25.4 |
+-------+------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 240   | NULL | 240                  |                                                9.44882 |
| 240,5 | NULL | 240.5                |                                                9.46850 |
| 9,448 | NULL | 9.448                |                                                0.37008 |
| 240   | NULL | 240                  |                                                9.44882 |
| 240,  | NULL | 240.                 |                                                9.44882 |
|  ,1   | NULL |  .1                  |                                                0.00394 |
| 1,0   | NULL | 1.0                  |                                                0.03937 |
| 0 ,1  | NULL | 0 .1                 |                                                0.00000 |
+-------+------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

I have no idea why there should be a difference between update and select. As a workaround you could tighten up on your replace something like this

```
    replace(
    REPLACE(trim(d), ',','.')
    ,' .','.')
```

As ever gigo you may need to tidy up d before you attempt updates.